# WSOD coming on opening the 1st page of drupal 7 project

Tags: postgresql, drupal, localhost, wsod

I have checked  `tail -n 20 /Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log`. No errors in log. I am using MAMP.

Also I have added

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

in `index.php`.

My memory limit in `php.ini` is

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Error log was not coming because i was adding code in index.php, it should have been added at the end of the settings.php file:

   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
   ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
2. After i checked logs, there were normal warnings. After that i enabled drush & it showed database is being connected but parameters are wrong. 
   Removing $database array from settings.php file and then installing like a fresh vanilla instance solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to enable clean URLs? Add this to .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at drupal's log.
With drush:

- drush en dblog
- drush ws